# Mutation Observer not working on a supported Microsoft Edge Version

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser, microsoft-edge

I have the following code which utilizes mutationobserver and it is working in the browser chrome, firefox, opera but not in the browser edge.

```
  var MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver || window.MozMutationObserver;
  var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {

   mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {

     if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
     if(mutation.target.innerHTML == 'Online - Chat Us'){
       //if button text changes from "Offline" to "Online - Chat Us"
       if(mutation.removedNodes[0].nodeValue === 'Offline' && mutation.addedNodes[0].nodeValue === 'Online - Chat Us'){
         //change top button to "Online - Chat Us" && false the disabled attribute.
         document.getElementById('mySecondButton').innerHTML = mutation.addedNodes[0].nodeValue;
         document.getElementById('mySecondButton').disabled = false;
     }
 }
     }else if(mutation.type === 'characterData'){
     //console.log(mutation);      
     }
   });
 });
```

Only within the edge browser in the debugger, I am receiving the following error: **SCRIPT5007: SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'nodeValue' of undefined or null reference** which is referencing this line of code `if(mutation.target.innerHTML === 'Chat Now'){`

From this chart below I can see that I am on a supported version.

[Link to chart resource](https://docs.w3cub.com/browser_support_tables/mutationobserver/)
[image]

Screenshot of edge browser version.

[image]

Comment: @calculuswhiz I am receiving the following error: SCRIPT5007: SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'nodeValue' of undefined or null reference

Comment: it is refering this line if(mutation.target.innerHTML == 'Chat Now'){ wondering if it has to do something with the innerHTML

Comment: @calculuswhiz Whenever the text inside a span is changed is currently triggering it. I'm going to replace the foreach with a for loop..

Comment: @Calculuswhiz Looks like the "target" and "removedNodes" properties are only supported in version 12. Have a look https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationRecord

Comment: According to the [MDN document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver), I have created [a sample](https://codepen.io/Dillion121/pen/zYGRrqq?editors=1000) and using your code, it seems that everything works well, can't reproduce the problem. Can you create a [codepen sample](https://codepen.io/pen/) to reproduce the problem?

Comment: In Edge, innerHTML, innerText, and textContent changes cause not one but two mutation records: one for the removal of the old node, and one for the insertion of the new node. All other browsers have only one mutation record that contains one removed and one inserted node. I provided some null checks to the script to narrow down the mutation records to only one and it was good to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Edge, innerHTML, innerText, and textContent changes cause not one but two mutation records: one for the removal of the old node, and one for the insertion of the new node. All other browsers have only one mutation record that contains one removed and one inserted node. I provided some null checks to the script to narrow down the mutation records to only one and it was good to go.